# Efficiently format dates from a log file with POSIX tools

Tags: shell, awk, posix

Context: in a POSIX-only project, I need to reformat a logfile, changing iso dates to UNIX timestamps. The log file looks like:

```
2022-01-11T18:22:46+0100    call_ring   +3366
2022-01-11T19:36:54+0100    call_ring   +33611
2022-01-12T07:49:15+0100    call_ring   +33616
2022-01-12T08:57:20+0100    call_ring   +33621
2022-01-12T09:42:56+0100    call_ring   +33648
2022-01-12T12:20:48+0100    call_ring   +3364
2022-01-12T12:28:01+0100    call_ring   +3364
2022-01-12T13:16:31+0100    call_ring   +33628
```

For now I use

```
awk -F'\t' '{cmd="date \"+%s\t"$3"\" -d "$1;system(cmd)}' logs.tsv
```

But on large files it's unbearably slow (more than 50s for ~20k lines). I believe the `system()` function forking 20k process is the cause.

Is there a way to be faster in a POSIX shell script? I'd like to avoid Python or perl for this, too.

(Note that `date -d` is not POSIX, we plan to write an in-house binary for this. Therefore `date -d` will be accepted in the answer)

Comment: How about using like: `awk -F'\t' '{fflush();cmd="date \"+%s\t"$3"\" -d "$1;system(cmd)}' logs.tsv` I haven't tested it yet, try it out once and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Also please do mention expected output in your question, we could try to do this within `awk` itself, let us know once question is edited with samples of output.

Comment: If you're writing a custom binary to convert the date string, why not extend it to also process a list of date strings as input. Or to just parse the logfile directly?

Comment: Take a look at `man 3 strftime`.

Comment: As @RavinderSingh13 already requested, please add the expected output for your posted sample input so we have something to test a potential solution against to know if it works or not.

Comment: One obvious speedup would be to only call `date` when the date changes and for all of the times that day you can just to math to calculate the change in seconds that day so instead of calling `date` once per input line you call it once per day change which if your timestamps average about 1 min apart would mean you call `date` 1,439 fewer times per day and do should speed up your code by several orders of magnitude. You may even be able to only call `date` once per month change or even once per year change, I haven't thought it through at all.

Comment: You want to avoid python or perl? What about C? C is POSIX...

Answer (score 3):

<fart age=old mode=grumpy> kids today! </>

```
$ cat <<EOF >calctime.awk
# this simplified formula only works 2000-03 to 2100-02 which I assume 
# should cover any logfile timestamps of interest today or the near future;
# it can fairly easily be extended as far back or forward as the Gregorian 
# calendar was/remains in use
# oops! offset was backward (the only thing I couldn't easily test at first)
{ split($1,a,/[-+T:]/);
  t = a[2]<=2;
  t = int((a[1]-2000-t)*365.25) + int((a[2]-3+t*12)*30.6+.5) + a[3]-1;
  t = t*86400 + a[4]*3600 + a[5]*60 + a[6] + 951868800;
  t += (substr($1,20,1)=="+"?-1:+1)*(substr(a[7],1,2)*3600+substr(a[7],3,2)*60);
  print t,$3; }
EOF
$ awk -f calctime.awk -v OFS='\t' infile >outfile # or pipe to something
```

Time less than 0.1 second.

Added: You should be able to see how this works if you take the 12 months of our (for Western cultures) calendar starting with March, as the Romans did, and see the lengths have a repeating pattern except for the last (February): 31-30-31-30-31 31-30-31-30-31 31-(28/29). As a result, the number of months from the March (numbered zero) 'under' a given month to that month (numbering Jan and Feb as 10 and 11 of the prior year) times 30.6 rounded to the nearest integer, implemented in awk by adding .5 and truncating, gives the number of *days* for that partial year; plus 365.25 times the number of years between 2000-03 and the March used; plus the day of month counting from zero gives the total days from 2000-03-01 to the desired date. Multiply the number of days by 86400 seconds per day and add the desired time of day gives seconds since 2000-03-01Tmidnight. Add the number of seconds from 1970-01-01Tmidnight (the Unix/POSIX epoch) to 2003-03-01Tmidnight, and adjust by the timezone offset for the desired time since Unix/POSIX is 'UTC' (really tweaked UTC without leapseconds, essentially mimicking the prior GMT, but in both cases without timezone or daylight/summer adjustment), and done.

I should note this is based on FORTRAN code I saw widely used around 1970, except that had the data fields (year,month,day,etc) already in numeric form -- FORTRAN didn't have a 'character' type you could parse until 1977, but it had formatted READ and WRITE since its creation -- and it was routinely written without explanation or claim of authorship apparently on the ground it was 'just obvious'. Of course it used different epochs, commonly 1900, because almost no one had heard of Unix then, but that's just a constant. And FORTRAN didn't (and its modern form Fortran still doesn't) have BCPL-C-awk-perl style mapping of boolean to integer 0/1, so you used truncating integer division like `(1-(M+9)/12)` or `((14-M)/12)`; you could (also) do that in awk but it needs explicit truncation with `int()`.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be directly answering your question, but I have benchmarked
between several solutions by generating 20,000 lines as the posted log file.

### OP's awk solution

```
#!/bin/sh

awk -F'\t' '{cmd="date \"+%s\t"$3"\" -d "$1;system(cmd)}' logs.tsv > /dev/null
```

took **59.5** seconds to complete.

### POSIX sh

```
#!/bin/sh

IFS=$(printf "\t")

while read -r a b c; do
    echo $(date +%s -d "$a")"$IFS$c"
done < logs.tsv > /dev/null
```

took **35.6** seconds.

### `date` command only

```
#!/bin/sh

i=0
while [ "$i" -lt 20000 ]; do
    date +%s -d "2022-01-11T18:22:46+0100"
    i=$(($i+1))
done > /dev/null
```

took **33.4** seconds.

It seems the most of the execution time is consumed by the `date` command.
If you plan to write your own substitution for `date -d`, it will be
significantly faster.

Comment: Not quite. awk `system()` runs a _shell_ which in turn runs `date`, and the cost of loading/starting a process is significantly more than the cost of the work done by either of these, thus the awk time is almost exactly double the time of either shell script, and a custom binary (which still involves creating a process each time) won't be noticably faster. And your 'POSIX sh' obviously has `echo` builtin, which is very common but not required, otherwise it would also be double.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I should have explained better. I wanted to focus on the difference between the `POSIX sh` version and the repetition of the `date` command, which is very small. I don't intend to embed the OP's custom binary into the `system()` function in awk, which includes overhead costs as you point out.

Comment: And as I said the difference is small _because_ you're using builtin `echo`; if you force the external echo on your system, typically `/bin/echo`, it will also be slower.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you could relax your POSIX-only requirement for a 150+ speed-up factor... With the GNU awk built-in `mktime` and `gensub` functions (tested with a 20k lines input):

```sh
$ time awk '{utc = gensub(/.*([+-][0-9]+)/,"\\1",1,$1);
             gsub(/-|T|:|\+[0-9]+/," ",$1);
             $1 = mktime($1, utc); print}' logs.tsv > tmp.tsv

real    0m0.290s
user    0m0.280s
sys     0m0.005s

$ head tmp.tsv
1641925366 call_ring +3366
1641929814 call_ring +33611
...
```

`gensub` extracts the UTC flags (e.g. `+0100`) from the first field, `gsub` reformats the first field as the space-separated string required by `mktime` (e.g. `2022 01 11 18 22 46`).

This version attempts to determine whether daylight saving time is in effect for the specified time. Replace `mktime($1, utc)` by:

- `mktime($1 " 1", utc)` if you want `awk` to assume daylight saving time,
- `mktime($1 " 0", utc)` if you want `awk` to assume standard time.